# How to check if all td tags contain specified text using xpath Selenium Java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I'm trying to check if all `td` tags contain specified text using xpath like:

```
 WebElement tableId = driver.findElement(By.id("tablepress-6"));
 if (!driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'" + textInput + "')]")).isEmpty()) {

 List<WebElement> tdElements = tableId.findElements(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'"+ textInput + "')]"));
          //...
 }
```

Also I've tried methods using xpath like:

```
List<WebElement> tdElements = tableId.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'" + textInput + "')]"));
```

And like:

```
List<WebElement> tdElements = tableId.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[*[text() = '"+ textInput + "']]/td[2]"));
```

But if I check my [website](https://openscience.in.ua/ua-journals) I'm not getting all matches for `td` elements, maybe because of `br` elements inside some of matched `td`.

[image]

Instead of getting all `17` matches (like on the screen above), I'm getting less number of matches:
[image]

Can someone suggest me the way how to get all `td` tags which contain specified text? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have struggled with [case sensitive issue of Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60357679/8370915). I have mixed text, but Selenium is case-sensitive, so I need to use whether lowercase or upper.

Answer (score 1):

Try using .getAttribute("textContent") instead of getText

Because getText or text() actually uses innerText ,and will not detect text from hidden elements .

> Don't get confused by the differences
>   between Node.textContent and HTMLElement.innerText. Although the names
>   seem similar, there are important differences:
>
> textContent gets the content of all elements,
>   including  and  elements. In contrast, innerText only
>   shows “human-readable” elements.
>
> textContent returns every element in the node. In
>   contrast, innerText is aware of styling and won’t return the text of
>   “hidden” elements.
>
> Moreover, since innerText takes CSS styles into account, reading the
>   value of innerText triggers a reflow to ensure up-to-date computed
>   styles. (Reflows can be computationally expensive, and thus should be
>   avoided when possible.)
>
> Unlike textContent, altering innerText in Internet Explorer (version
>   11 and below) removes child nodes from the element and permanently
>   destroys all descendant text nodes. It is impossible to insert the
>   nodes again into any other element or into the same element after
>   doing so

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try to adapt it in my code. But for now I'm getting `null`, if I use: `String tdTextMatches = tableId.getAttribute("Physics and astronomy")` instead of `List<WebElement> tdElements = tableId.findElements(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Physics and astronomy')]"));`

Comment: @invzbl3 you have to use tableId.getAttribute("textContent") not the actual text

Comment: Okay, I got it. I've checked how it works and it gives me more content then I need. For me important is only specified text from `td`. I suppose the main problem is now how to get firstly `List<WebElement> tdElements` using correct xpath and only then to find something using like `.getAttribute("textContent")`